# What does this coil do in car door handle

Tags: automotive, coil, electromagnetic

This door handle is from a Range Rover L405. I tried searching car manufacturer's documentation and car door handle tear downs, but I cannot find what this coil is doing in the the door handle.

[image: Coil]

This is where it is located in the handle. There are no other components near the coil. The capacitative sensors are on the right side of it (around the round button).

[image: Car door handle]

Is it used as an electromagnet to detect when the door handle is being pulled?

Comment: I would buy a used part rather than try to repair that one.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica I am not repairing it. I am trying to understand what’s going on inside of it.

Answer (score 4):

I’d guess that is a transmit coil for the passive keyless entry system. It sends a low frequency magnetic signal that is picked up by a small coil in the key fob. The fob recognizes the signal and then transmits an “unlock” request over a much higher radio frequency (same as if you pushed the “unlock” button on the fob). Of course both signals have some security encryption. But hackers are also looking for ways to beat it.

Comment: Thank you! This sounds more plausible than my guess.